# Where is the data sent to the server when the ajax data is not a map?

Tags: jquery, spring

I suddenly sent ajax data to send it as a normal data type, not as an object.
I wonder if the server received this data. Is there a way to check?

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/hw/admin/"+insertType,
    type : "post",
    async : false,
    data : 111,
    success : function(data) {
        if (data == 0)
            alert("error")
        else {
            alert("Success!!!");
            $("textarea", "input").attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }
    },
    error : function(data, source, err) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(source);
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

The above code does not cause an error. I wonder what happened to 111.

Comment: if (data = 0) is wrong, it is doing an assignment not a compare

Comment: You need to give us more information.  Are you saying that 111 is not showing up at "/hw/admin"+insertType? and what is insertType?

Comment: InsertType is a type of query such as insert, update, and delete. I am using spring 4.0 and know that there are post and get methods when passing data. We also know that we need to pass in an object with key and value. However, I am wondering if server-side 111 has been sent when I see that it does not cause an error even if I send it by ignoring the data format. I think it's a fun way to send data using $ .ajax if it can be passed to the server and the value can be found.

Comment: Sorry, `data =0` is my fault. Apart from that, ajax did not cause any syntax error.

Comment: change async to true and try it

Comment: I have not see data submitted as a single value.  Everything I have down has been in key/ value pairs.